# PHP Real time sessions control. How?

Tags: php, session

How can I make a real-time PHP sessions control? I mean, when a user logs in, I create a PHP session (`$_SESSION[]`) and I store it in a table (MySQL) but how can I tell when the user logs out? I can obviously detect when the user logs out and destroy the session but what happens if the user never clicks **log out** how can I detect whenever the session is closed?
Thanks!

Comment: You can update your table the time each time the user interacts in your website, and take those who didn't act as logout.

Comment: You don't. Either you use a hidden frame that refreshes automatically every *n* seconds, an ajax to make the 'heartbeat' or some other method envolving images or something

Comment: Sessions automatically expire after a defined timeout (24 minutes by default). The session cookie can also be configured to expire when the browser window closes rather than after a time-since-last-request.

Comment: you can't. there's NO 100% reliable method of figuring out/detecting when a user leaves your site, closes the tab/window your site is in, etc.. At best you can set a relatively short expiry time on the session and just say "User was last seen within the last X minutes".

Answer (score 1):

That is a common problem. When a user don't click on the Logout button the session is available again. Normally the garbage collector clean the session after a defined time.

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Here is a good tutorial how to build a MySQL session handler. So let PHP manage that part.

Important part is here:

```
<?php
// set our custom session functions.
session_set_save_handler(array($this, 'open'), 
array($this, 'close'), 
array($this, 'read'), 
array($this, 'write'), 
array($this, 'destroy'), 
array($this, 'gc'));

// This line prevents unexpected effects
//when using objects as save handlers.
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
?>
```

With the last array you define the function to clean up your sessions.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem but I solved that by creating another id so I do not have to use SESSION ID (I think its not secure) so every time the user logs in my system he gets another ID, my function that checks if an user is authorized checks the user ID on the database which is also saved on my session to check if it's equal to the ID on my Database.

I think this is another security measure to ensure that i have only one instance of a user logged in and I had no problems with this until now.

But if you MUST know when the user has disconnected of your system, this won't help.